# Gradle error: Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying do use the Apache httpclient for Android in my Gradle project and I don't understand why I get this error when running `./gradle build`:

> Could not find org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1.

My top-level build.gradle contains:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
```

My project build.gradle starts with:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':workspace:google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
}
```

What's wrong with that?

In The Central Repository Browser of Maven the package I need is listed:
http://search.maven.org/#browse|-305040853

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add in your **project** `build.gradle`

```
 repositories {
        mavenCentral()
 }
```

If you would like to put it in the top level file you can add this in the **top level** `build.gradle`:

```
allprojects {
     repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, so easy! I thought everything in the top level build file was valid for the projects, too. Thanks!

Comment: @MaxGyver You can also add it in the top level build.gradle file. I've update the answer.